# Pass a NSString from Child to Parent for ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

My parent ViewController class contains a UISearchBar. I have a UIButton that will push on a new ViewController via the code below

```
AddViewController *addViewController = [[AddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];
[addViewController release];
```

In the AddViewController the User is presented with a TableView of animal names. On the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I extract the the animal name and store it in an NSString. I then dismiss the AddViewController by

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My Question is How do I pass the NSString animal name to the Parent ViewController of AddViewController? I'm attempting to place the animal name in the UISearchBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a Delegate.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

These allow you to communicate with the parent view controller, and in your case, pass a variable.

Comment: I wouldn't say "need to" - that's one way you *could* though. :-)

Comment: There is no other way to do this cleanly. If multiple variables needed to be passed, using a delegate would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property in the parent view controller which you can then update from the child by calling

```
self.parentViewController.searchBarText = animalNameString;
```

When the child is dismissed, set the UISearchBar text in the parent's viewWillAppear method