# Call a method in parent from within modalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I add a viewcontroller using

```
[self presentModalViewController:vectorView animated:YES];
```

But then from within would like to call a method inside the parent viewcontroller.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125226/pass-a-nsstring-from-child-to-parent-for-modalviewcontroller) question and found that something like this could be done to set a variable in the parent:

```
self.parentViewController.myString = aString;
```

But is there a way to call a method and send a few variables through that way?

For example

```
self.parentViewController.myMethod; //Which does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no different from any other message you would send:

```
[self.parentViewController myMethod:param1 withParam:param2];
```

Note that the behavior of the `parentViewController` property has changed in iOS 5:

> Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and was being presented modally, the view controller that was presenting it would be returned. This is no longer the case. You can get the presenting view controller using the presentingViewController property.

Comment: Cool. Had to use `presentingViewController` instead to make it work. So thanks for the extra.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Ole Begemann answer, you can cast your view controller to silence warnings

```
if ([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[YourParentViewController class]])
    [(YourParentViewController*)self.parentViewController yourMethod];
```